# How can I make the MacOS lock screen wait longer at the password prompt before turning off the screen?

Tags: password, screensaver, screen-lock

My Macbook is connected to an external monitor that takes a full minute to turn on (it scans through it's half-dozen inputs, taking 10 seconds for each one). When I wake up my Macbook, if I simply wait for the password prompt to appear on the monitor, it never appears, because the Macbook goes back to sleep before the monitor is ready. To work around this, I have to press keys on the keyboard while the screen is blank to make MacOS think that I'm typing, until the screen finally finishes its morning routine. Is there any way to change this timeout to something longer, like 5 minutes, to accommodate this very slow monitor?

(I can't simply type in the password while the screen is off, because if the screen was ever already unlocked, then for all I know I could be typing my password into a chat window or a tweet.)

Comment: I would check your monitor settings to see if you can turn off the scan.  Waiting a full minute plus just to see what’s on the screen is an eternity.

Comment: @Allan I use multiple computers plugged into different inputs, so disabling the scan would mean I have to manually switch the input every time I switch computers, which is even more annoying.

Comment: I don’t understand this then.  If the worry is you can’t type your password becase it “might go into a chat window or a tweet”, then your screen is active.  Making the login appear longer would be moot.  Additionally, manually pressing the input to select it (assuming your using this as a KVM), is a *safety mechanism* to ensure you’re on the correct input and you don’t type your password on the wrong screen.

Comment: @Allan My point is that I can't immediately tell whether or not the OS is locked until the screen comes on. It might not have been idle long enough to lock even though the screen turned off, for example. So I have to wait until the screen is on to start typing my password, so I know for sure I'm typing it on the lock screen. The screen is not a KVM. I have a manual switch swapping for my USB devices from one machine to the other (i.e. a KVM without the V), and then I rely on the monitor to auto-switch to whichever machine is currently sending pixels down the wire.

Comment: In short, I have already explored the option of wiring things differently or configuring the monitor differently, and none of those options are better than what I have now. I'm just looking for an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: Have you considered turning off the need to enter a password?

Comment: @DavidAnderson This is a work machine that is configured to require a password. But even if it wasn't, I am not looking for a solution that involves disabling the security of my computer.

Comment: This appears to be a hard coded 30 second timeout (I timed mine).  My suggestion is to move your mouse or tap a modifier key (like `Cmd`) every few seconds until the screen lights up.